# Python Dash standalone HTML file same as Plotly

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash

I usually do plots with Plotly and save them as standalone HTML files, which is extremely convenient for sharing them with colleagues and to "freeze" the data that is being displayed. [This](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/SengerM/html-github-hosting/blob/main/201120%2037th%20RD50%20Workshop/Signal%2001191-B.html) is an example I made with

```
plotly.offline.plot(
    plotly_plot, 
    filename = 'standalone great plot.html',
)
```

Now I want to do the same with a very simple Dash app that has no server-side requirements at all, it is just a bunch of Plotly figures and some text. How can I do this?

### Example of what I want

Consider the first example that is shown in [this tutorial](https://dash.plotly.com/layout), which I copy-paste here for easiness:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Run this app with `python app.py` and
# visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ in your web browser.

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I run this with Python and then open http://127.0.0.1:8050/ in my browser I see this:

[image]

so as can be seen this is basically a single Plotly figure with some text. So it **must be somehow possible to produce the standalone HTML file** with this content.

I want to replicate the behavior of `plotly.offline.plot` with this. How can I do it? I have tried to do "File → Save Page As" in my web browser but the resulting HTML fails to display because the server (the Python `app.py` file) is not running.

Comment: you can't produce standalone HTML. Dash doesn't put data and plots directly in HTML. It puts only JavaScript code which later read layout, data and plots from server.

Comment: It must be possible, the most complicated component is the plot and I am already saving it as a standalone HTML. The rest is just some static text with the plot embedded.

Comment: but dash doesn't use it as in normal plotly. It sends only JavaScript code to browser - and this code sends request to server for data - layout as JSON data - and it use it to generate page. You would have to remove all JavaScript and put all code with data - so you would have to rewrite all from scratch.

Comment: You could render the HTML output to PDF and share the PDF file. Create a print media stylesheet or something similar to control the layout and then print to PDF using tools such as Playwright.

Comment: not sure if anyone still looking for the answer, but I have the same question and it was answered by this gentleman. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75303301/export-plotly-dash-to-html-from-callback/75304741#75304741> and also Plotly Dash has the page document the download function <https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/download>

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to save plotly dash into an html file.

https://community.plotly.com/t/export-html-of-dash-app/26754/2

https://community.plotly.com/t/feature-request-html-embedded-layout-and-dependency-lookup-for-standalone-html-dash-reports/49149

Answer (score 2):

The subject is old but I was looking for the same question for making a html file with clickable dashtable.

For standalone plotly figure with static text, you could have a look at jupyter notebook. notebook can be convert to standalone html file while keeping interactive plot.