# Export plotly dash to html from callback

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to export the dynamic dash plot to html. here is my code, when I click download as html after the plot appear, I was only able to download an empty plot, it came back nothing.
What went wrong? thank you

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html,Input, Output, callback,dash_table
import plotly.express as px
from base64 import b64encode
import io

app = Dash(__name__)

buffer = io.StringIO()
df=tem1 # tem1 is my own dataset
html_bytes = buffer.getvalue().encode()
encoded = b64encode(html_bytes).decode()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Test Graph'),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id="checklist",
        options=['A','B','C'],
        value=['A','B','C'],
        inline=True),
    html.A(
        html.Button("Download as HTML"), 
        id="download",
        href="data:text/html;base64," + encoded,
        download="plotly_graph.html"
    )
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"), 
    Input("checklist", "value"))
def update_line_chart(Programs):
    mask = df.Program.isin(Programs)
    fig = px.line(df[mask], 
        x="Month", y="Mood", color='Group',text='Module')
    return fig

@app.callback(
    Output('download','n_clicks'),
    [Input('graph','figure')])
def download_html(n):
    return n.write_html(buffer)

app.run_server(debug=False,port=8051)
```

I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575513/export-plot-to-html-from-callback), but it couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your referred code is my question and I think you should fix it as below:

- Add `dcc.Download`
- Save fig to html first
- Use `dcc.send_file` to download html file

I don't have your df so please refer below code:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html,Input, Output, callback,dash_table
import plotly.express as px
from base64 import b64encode
import io

app = Dash(__name__)

df = px.data.gapminder()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Test Graph'),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph",figure=fig),
    dcc.Checklist(
        id="checklist",
        options=['A','B','C'],
        value=['A','B','C'],
        inline=True),
    html.A(
        html.Button("Download as HTML"), 
        id="download"
    ),
    dcc.Download(id='download_1')
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"), 
    Input("checklist", "value"))
def update_line_chart(Programs):
    fig = px.scatter(df.query("year==2007"), x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
                 size="pop", color="continent",
                 hover_name="country", log_x=True, size_max=60)
    fig.write_html("plotly_graph.html")
    return fig

@app.callback(
    Output('download_1','data'),
    Input('download','n_clicks'),prevent_initial_call=True)
def download_html(n):
    return dcc.send_file("plotly_graph.html")

app.run_server(debug=False,port=8051)
```

Hope this help

Comment: it worked successfully, thanks , but one question, my originally plot  has option to select different program A,B,C, but my downloaded plot lost that. Do you know why?

Comment: @eidui: As I said I dont have your df so I can create graph like your. You should revise your code based on mine

Comment: I did revise the code, but when I tried download the plot, only the plot itself was downloaded, the title 'Test Graph' is missing,  also the checklist component , so I wonder what could go wrong that some components are not downloaded.

Comment: @eidui: So your goal is download full page, not only the graph right?

Comment: that's correct, because when running on server, that graph is interactive and has every component, but this download missing everything else except the graph itself, no title, no  radio buttons or checklist display, which is hard to present. Is there a way to export the full page? I tried looking up online, but no luck.

Comment: @eidui: I don't think it's possible. If you want to present to other person, I think you should deploy your app to somewhere like render.